# ng-animate don't work in my IONIC app

Tags: angularjs, animation, ionic-framework, ng-animate

i'm new at Ionic. I'm try to add the animations with this tutorial:

http://gonehybrid.com/how-to-animate-your-ionic-app-with-animate-css-and-nganimate/

all work well until the nganimate step. I don't know why but if i add a custom class like the example nothing happen. Here's my code (p.s. i din't edit my app.js. ng-animate is included in Ionic right?):

```
 <ion-content has-bouncing="false">
        <a class="whiteBack" />
        <div class="staffList">

            <a class="item item-avatar animate patate">
                <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/general04/png/256/clients.png">
                <h2>Stefano Z.</h2>
                <p>iOS & Android App Developer</p>
            </a>
    </ion-content>
```

CSS:

```
 /*animation*/ 
    patate.ng-enter {
        -webkit-animation: fadeInLeft 1s;
      animation: fadeInLeft 1s;
    }
```

probably i miss something in my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
     <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/0.9.23/js/angular/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

ng-animate is included in Ionic framework,
just need to apply the `animated` class, and it should come before the animation effect, i.e: `class="animated fade-in-out"`

So maybe this:

```
<a class="item item-avatar animate patate">
```

Should be:

```
<a class="item item-avatar animated patate">
```

Comment: don't work. I don't know why but ng-enter class didn't applicate

Answer (score 0):

You can add "ng-animate-children" attribute like this:

`<body ng-app="starter" ng-animate-children="true">`

For detail:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate/directive/ngAnimateChildren

Answer (score 0):

Ionic has a lot of problems with ng-animate (bugs). Try using angular1.3.0 and Ionic1.3.2